# HL7 CDA Undefined clinical data

Tags: java, undefined, hl7, medical, cda

I recently started studying [HL7 CDA r2 documents](https://www.projects.openhealthtools.org/sf/sfmain/do/downloadAttachment/projects.mdht/discussion.modeling_users.topc11806/post21022;jsessionid=F61FD76C449F7962A6461B9DECE60ACB?id=atch5088), because I have some clinical data that needs to be as HL7 standards demands.

My doubt is the data I have (Body Mass Index (BMI), Weight, Height,BMI State, Sex, Age, Name ) doesn't fit in any template that CDA has.

**Question:** So, how can I build a CDA document with the data I have??

Comment: Provide some links to the respective documents you studied.

Comment: https://www.projects.openhealthtools.org/sf/sfmain/do/downloadAttachment/projects.mdht/discussion.modeling_users.topc11806/post21022;jsessionid=F61FD76C449F7962A6461B9DECE60ACB?id=atch5088 - This ones is the Implementation Guide for CDA Release 2.0 Consolidated CDA Templates, which is the document that defines how to build a CDA document

Comment: Please, can anybody give me some advices??? I'd trully appreciate..

Comment: This is a programming QA site. You haven't specified a programming language, neither you presented a sample of code. What do you expect exactly?

Comment: The programming language I'll use is Java, but that's the least important right now, I just want to know if I can build a CDA document just with the data I've specified before, and if so how can I do that. You see, the problem is that I can't make the data I have fit in any template that CDA has. I'm complelety lost with this hl7 cda stuff... I just wanted to be able to build a CDA document with the data that I have available(Body Mass Index (BMI), Weight, Height,BMI State, Sex, Age, Name )

Comment: I realize you asked this months ago, but you may want to look at the following thread which references a number of tools available for building CDAs: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239827/looking-for-a-library-to-process-cda-aka-hl7v3-aka-ccd-messages-in-java Your data looks entirely appropriate to a clinical document and most would appears in numerous CDA type documents.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to produce a CDA-compliant document would be to create an account on Microsoft [HealthVault](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/healthvault/), enter the supplied information, and export as a CCD (via menus: Health Information -> More Actions -> Export Information). This will give you a CDA-compliant XML document constrained by the CCD schema, which you can find in the [Things reference](http://developer.healthvault.com/pages/types/types.aspx?/types/schema.aspx?id=1e1ccbfc-a55d-4d91-8940-fa2fbf73c195).

CDA only describes a generic XML structure based on HL7v3 RIM. There are multiple schemas (CCD, C32, C80, C83) which constrain this structure into something more usable. As a general rule, saying that you have a CDA document is not very helpful, since you will not be able to tightly validate or parse the data without further constraints. See [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107944/cda-ccd-hl7-version-3) about the difference between CDA and CCD.

Comment: Well said, however one small correction that CCD, C32, etc are all implementation guides and schematrons are used to assert conformance, not schemas. All are valid aginst the CDA schema. Also, the latest implementation guide is Consolidated CDA which is currently US specific. However, the HL7 StrucDocs workgroup is working on publishing an international version of C-CDA.

Comment: CCD or HITSP C32, as well as others, is a document level template, not a schema. They are not valid against a typical CDA schema since "templateId"'s are not defined in pure CDA. Other than that Seth and Tone are correct. If some of you is interested expanding knowledge regarding CCD you may look at "Unofficial Developer's Guide to CCD on Mirth Connect” eBook available at - http://ccdonmirth.shamilpublishing.com

Comment: The link to MS HealthVault is dead (x_X) New link is https://international.healthvault.com

Answer (score 0):

CDA implementations work using implementation guides that defines the data to be contained in a specific type of CDA to be used in a specific context. You should use other's implementation guides that includes the data you want to model (there are a lot online, you will find them by just googling), or create your own implementation guide and define your own templates (I tend to end doing this almost every time for my clients since they need to model very specific clinical data).